# Change current directory and view available directories

Tags: python, directory, python-2.x, cd

This isnt a duplicate, as the original answer did not help into implementing it into my raw input command interpreter. Credit to original question/answer where due.

So I'm working on a DOS style Operating System in python and I was wondering how or even if it is possible to execute a command that would let me switch between directories like a regular command prompt would let you do.

Im not sure how well I'm explaining myself but basically I would have the same command as `cd` in terminal so I could read files imbedded in folders, change between folders etc. I don't need any sort of limit on how complex it is but i would prefer if it isn't too long.

I have yet to find a clear solution to this. in a best case scenario, this is all you would need to input

```
cd folder1
cd folderinfolder1
```

this would be inputted into a `raw input` or a `input` and then executed so im assuming it would require splits so it knows that before the space there is `cd` and after the space there is the filename, such as `folder`
I am also have an issue with using `os.listdir` only showing files, and not any folders.

it would be used like this

`directory=raw_input("enter cd followed with a directory")`

---

This might be a bit much to ask, not even sure if it is possible

Comment: [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#files-and-directories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import os`

`os.chdir('folder1')`

or

`os.chdir('folderinfolder1')`

Comment: that would be changing the directory overall. what im looking for is that you would be using a raw input to determine that you would want to run this command and at the same time know what directory to refrence

Comment: `if 'cd' in directory:`

`desired_directory = directory.split(' ')[1]`

`os.chdir('desired_directory')`

Comment: Last question, is there an easy way to print the current directory

Comment: os.getcwd()... there are plenty of other functions you may be interested in at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The only problem i see with os.getcwd() is that it list the entire path, not just the current directory, shouldve specified that

Comment: try this: `full_path = os.getcwd()`


`split_path = full_path.split('\\')`


`current_folder = split_path[-1]`

Answer (score -1):

I have done this except using ***C*** while creating a shell, in my case I used a library with the ***chdir*** function and it looked like this:

```
static void min_cmd_cd_av(char *av, char ***env)
{
    char    *tmp;

    if (av && 0 == chdir(av))
    {
        tmp = min_env_get_val(env, "PWD=");
        min_env_set_path(env, "OLDPWD=", tmp);
        free(tmp);
        tmp = (char *)ft_memalloc(4098 * sizeof(char *));
        getcwd(tmp, 4098);
        min_env_set_path(env, "PWD=", tmp);
        ft_strdel(&tmp);
    }
    else
        ft_printf("\e[91mERROR: Invalid Path/Permissions\e[96m\n");
}

int         min_cmd_cd(int ac, char **av, char ***env)
{
    char    *tmp;

    if (ac <= 1)
    {
        tmp = min_env_get_val(env, "HOME=");
        if (tmp)
        {
            min_cmd_cd_av(tmp, env);
            ft_strdel(&tmp);
        }
        else
            ft_printf("\e[91mERROR: Home variable not found!\e[96m\n");
    }
    else if (ac > 1)
    {
        min_shell_path(&av, env);
        min_cmd_cd_av(av[1], env);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

I used the shell environment to update the PWD and OLDPWD which allows you to implement that into your shell as well.

Comment: Using python 2.7 IDLE for programming, not C